# calculate the correlation between a several time series

Tags: matlab, correlation

If I have a matrix:

```
data = rand(365,5);
```

What is the most appropriate way of calculating the correlation between each column and the mean of the remaining columns. For example, for the first column:

```
  R = nonzeros(tril(corrcoef(data(:,1),mean(data(:,2:end)')'),-1));
```

How could I repeat this procedure so that I have 5 correlation values i.e. for each series?

EDIT:

Thanks for the comments. This could also be done in one line:

```
R = arrayfun(@(x)nonzeros(tril(corrcoef(data(:,x),...
    mean(data(:,setdiff(1:size(data,2),x))')'),-1)),1:size(data,2));
```

for those who wish to avoid loops. Although in this case the methods shown below are better due to their readability.

Comment: Does `corrcoef(data)` not work? It should return a 5x5 matrix containing the correlations between all possible combinations of the columns.

Comment: It does work just not for what I need. I want to calculate the correlation between each column and the mean of the other columns not the correlation between each column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i=1:5
    x = data(:,i);
    y = mean(data(:,(1:5) ~= i)')';
    R(i) = nonzeros(tril(corrcoef(x,y),-1));
end
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly simplified version:

```
R = zeros(1,5);
for i=1:5
    x = data(:,i);
    y = mean(data(:,(1:5)~=i), 2);
    R(i) = corr(x,y);
end
```

Comment: many thanks. Can also avoid loops by using the method shown above (EDIT)

Comment: @Kate: you are not really avoiding loops, ARRAYFUN basically has a loop hidden inside it. Not to mention this is way more readable..